# ListView data gets changed when i scroll the list

Tags: android, listview

I am using a listview with textview and checkbox. Where i load data from a service.

I am displaying **20 items** in list and when i click **next button**, i display another 20 items.
It is loading properly when i click **next button** but when i start scrolling down to see last value of list and move to top again, the data is getting jumbled and finally settles down with 7 values which gets repeated in the list among 20 items(7+7+6). When i click on single item **checkbox**, the same item which is repeated in list gets checked.

**My getView() method of my adapter:**

**Edited:**

```
     package android.virtus;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

CheckBox box;
ArrayList<String> textView1;
ArrayList<String> textView2;
ArrayList<String> textView3;


int listsize;
int i=0;
int size=20;


public Adapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> textView1, ArrayList<String> textView2, ArrayList<String> textView3,int listsize) {

    this.context=c;
    this.textView1=textView1;
    this.textView2=textView2;
    this.textView3=textView3;
    this.listsize=listsize;
    i=0;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return size;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

   public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view=arg1;


    ViewHolder holder=null;


    if (view == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tV1);
        holder.tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tV2);
        holder.tv3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tV3);
        holder.cb=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cB);


        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    }

        if(listsize==20){

            holder.tv1.setText(textView1.get(position));
            holder.tv2.setText(textView2.get(position));
            holder.tv3.setText(textView3.get(position));    

            view.setId(position);
        }else{  

        int index=listsize-20;

        if(i<19){ 

            i=i+1;
            holder.tv1.setText(textView1.get(index+i));
            holder.tv2.setText(textView2.get(index+i));
            holder.tv3.setText(textView3.get(index+i));

            view.setId(index+i);

            }else{

            }
              }

    return view;

}

private static class ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    protected CheckBox cb;

  }
 }
```

I am loading 100 items from service to a array list and displaying 20 in list, when i click next Button i display another 20 items from array list.

**Edit:**

In first image i checked first item, after scrolling see second image the same item which repeated gets checked automatically..

[image][image]

Comment: you are only setting the text to the textView for the first 20 item in the listView?

Comment: @sravani i want to use same approach. how are you loading the data when scroll down.

Comment: Paste your ViewHolder  class

Comment: can we see an example picture of the result?